# How to get the applied style name in word template from C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am trying to find the style name that are applied to my table and based on that i have to apply the width to the table.
here is the code.

```
 public void MakePageWidth(Word.Document document,bool Paragraphs = false)
    {
float nleftIndent = document.Application.CentimetersToPoints(Constants.LEFT_INDENT);
document.Application.Selection.Paragraphs.LeftIndent = nleftIndent;
}
```

how to find the name of the style that r applied to my paragraph.

Comment: Do you mean to get the font name?

Comment: No. i mean how to get the style name.i have created one style called "company" and in the code i want the name of the style say "company" based on selection of the paragraph.

Comment: are you want use the  third party library? if you want i can slove your question.

Comment: No thanks.without any third party library is it not possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Object styleobject = document.Application.Selection.get_Style();
string stylename=((Word.Style)styleobject).NameLocal;
```

I have tried this.its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the style and properties using the get_Style() function. This is a dynamic object, hence you dont get what are the properties available within it. However in the debug mode you can get all the properties of it. For example if you want to retrieve the style name you can use the following,

```
document.Application.Selection.get_Style().NameLocal;
```

Comment: I am getting an error "Object does not contain a definition for NameLocal " and no extension method "NameLocal" accepting the first argument of type "object" could be found.